# jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js is killing my selectList()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

Or maybe its the other way around?

I am new MVC so be gentle. I can select a value from a `Html.DropDownList` and it populates to the model when saved. However if I click out of the box `jQuery.Validate` barks at me with an error about null data.

This is the error

```
+       this    function( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    }   Object, (Function)
```

This is the view

```
@model Game.Domain.Equipment

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BaseGameObject.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BaseGameObject.Name) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BaseGameObject.Name)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BaseGameObject.Description)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BaseGameObject.Description) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BaseGameObject.Description)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type)
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Game.Domain.EquipmentType))))
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value)
</div>
```

This is the model

```
namespace Game.Domain
{
    public class Equipment
    {
        public Equipment()
        {
            BaseGameObject = new BaseGameObject();
        }

        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual BaseGameObject BaseGameObject { get; set; }
        public virtual EquipmentType Type { get; set; }

        public virtual int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have attempted to turn off the jvalidate jquery with jquery

```
$(function () {
    var select = $('select');
    $('select').attr("willValidate", false)
});
```

But no matter what I try I get same jvalidate error over and over. Its damned annoying =)

Comment: am I right to understand that your form submits as long as you pick a value in your select box and that your issue is the error msg flashing if u unselect the value before submitting?

Comment: Yes, when I click submit the error is thrown before the model saves back to the database.

Comment: do you have [required] annotation in your model applied to the id picked by the drop down? is a value selcted when you hit submit and get a validation error?

Comment: are you populating either of the int id s? and do you leave the dropdown unselected when the validation error comes up?

Comment: I do not have a required annotation in the model. When I hit submit i get the mentioned error first, as the drop down list is unselected. If I continue The value saves correctly to the database. I do not populate either id, I leave that to EF, and the value changes in the dropdown list successfully, its when I leave the field.

Comment: funky situation you ran into. non-nullable ints applied with MVC helpers automatically get [required]. I've lost countless hours in many instances over this icky problem.

Comment: Also note that dropdowns usually get a hidden field rendered next to them with same name so make sure your validate is looking at the right element by using ID or another selector or put an ignore on it via ignore option in validate set to the selector.

Comment: I'm not getting this error.  I don't think it is to do with nullable ints.  What versions of MVC, jQuery and the 'unobtrusive' script are you using?

Comment: I've had this happen with MVC 2,3,4. Nullable int's will always cause a field to behave like it is [required]. but @politus, I can't speak for your situation w/o a code sample...

Comment: @Siegeon Answered this very issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822540/syntax-error-with-parsejson-during-unobtrusive-validation/14822755#comment20792118_14822755